# Is there a both bold and slanted Computer Modern typeface?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, typefaces

Note: the font has to be loaded in plain TeX with `\font\bs=<nome_font>`

Comment: Which engine? pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX...?

Comment: @morbusg With Knuth's TeX

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a bold extended slanted cm font, but only in 10pt -- `cmbxsl10`.

basing the loading on what's in `plain.tex` and the `tugboat` style file, we get

```
\font\tenbs=cmbxsl10
\skewchar\tenbs='177
\font\twelvebs=cmbxsl12 scaled \magstep1
\skewchar\twelvebs='177
```

take a look at `tugboat.sty` (included in tex live).

by the way, `\bs` isn't a great name for this; it's often used as a synonym for
`\backslash`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\font\bs=cs-lmbxo10 at 14 pt
foo
\bs bar

\bye
```

It uses the latin modern, nearly the same as computer modern.

Comment: that's italic, not slanted...

Comment: sure, change the `i` to `o` and it will be slanted which is a lousy font ...